# django how to use get_or_create with a FileField and an upload_to

Tags: django

I have a website that where users upload data files. To prevent users from uploading duplicate data files, I'm using Django's `get_or_create`, which was working fine, until I added an `upload_to` to the model.

This is my model:

```
class TestFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='data/%Y/%m/')
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    welded_part = models.ForeignKey(WeldedPart, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)
```

Uploading the file calls the following function:

```
def process_data_file(myfile, my_id):
    a, created = TestFile.objects.get_or_create(file=myfile)
    if created:
        # do some number crunching here
        a.welded_part = my_id
        a.save()
    return created
```

If I try to upload testfile.xyz it checks for an object where `TestFile.object = 'testfile.xyz'`.

I will never find a duplicate file because the object stores the file as `'data/2018/04/testfile.xyz'`, not as `'testfile.xyz'`.

What's the proper way to use `get_or_create` in this instance?

I'm using django 1.11.3

Comment: When you say prevent user from uploading duplicate data files, you mean to avoid the same name on the server or prevent the same file itself?

Comment: be aware that with `/%Y/%m/` you will always have the current year and month added to the path of your uploaded file.

Comment: prevent the same file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I solved this. I added a filename `CharField` to my model. And a better path that doesn't depend on the date, instead the path depends on important parts of the filename.

```
def testfilepath(instance, filename):
    return 'testdata/%s/%s/%s' % (str(filename)[:4] , str(filename)[4:6] , str(filename))


class TestFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=testfilepath)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True) 
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    welded_part = models.ForeignKey(WeldedPart, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So now I can check the `get_or_create` on the filename, which doesn't include the path

```
def process_data_file(myfile, my_id):
    a, created = TestFile.objects.get_or_create(filename=str(myfile))
    if created:
        do some number crunching here
        a.file = myfile 
        a.welded_part = my_id
        a.save()
    return created
```